# jquery html() and append() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for some reason both methods results are TextNode. It means that browser doesnot parse content of appended string.

for example

```
var code = "<div><p>Some</p> words are <span>here</span></div>"
$("#news_details").append(code);
```

on the page I do have content

```
"<div><p>Some</p> news are <span>here</span></div>"
```

this

```
$("#news_details").contents()
```

shows that string with html source is attached(for some reason unknown to me) as single textnode

but if will type in firebug

```
var text = $('#news_detaisl').text()
$('#news_details').contents().remove()
$('#news_details').append(text)
```

and after that, it is parsed and shows in a right way.

Comment: forgot to say that append and html behave same.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with your supposition and not the code, which is of course in use by countless thousands of web sites and web applications.

Comment: you can't append a textNode, only an object
take a look at prc322's answer

Answer (score 2):

user the `html()`

```
var code = "<div><p>Some</p> words are <span>here</span></div>"
$("#news_details").html(code);
```

Comment: this example in my case will result addtional TextNode inside $("#news_details") with inner text = "<div><p>Some</p> words are <span>here</span></div>"

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't asked a question directly I can only assume what you want. Try this and tell me if it helps and if it was what you wanted:

```
var code = "<div><p>Some</p> words are <span>here</span></div>"
$("#news_details").append($(code));
```

Oh and $().append and $().html do NOT behave in the same way. $().append adds the input as a new child while $().html either returns the innerHTML of an element or sets it. Depending on whether you set a parameter.

Comment: $("#news_details").append("html code") only appends html code to content of the page. I can see on screen all tags everything. html code doesnot get parsed becouse if it is then i will see only what is between div tags

Comment: Errr...okay, let's do this with jsFiddle. Works like charm for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xCDxN/

Answer (score 0):

only this code works fine, but such a weird behavior

```
var content = news.newsDetails(here async ajax request which load html snippet with content);  //content is a string with html snippet from server

$("#news_content").append(content);
var value = $(".news_title").text();
$(".news_title").contents().remove();
$(".news_title").append(value);
$(".news_details").css('display','block')
```

and html snippet

```
<div class="news_details">
    <img class="pointer" src="/static/img/close6.png" alt="close" width='16' height='16'>
    <div class="news_head gradient">
        <span>{{ item.pub_date|date:"d M Y"  }}</span>{{ item.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="news_title">{{ item.full_text }}</div>
```